# Docker-compose scale command from within container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to build a topology which has service X and Y,
is it possible to scale service X from within service Y (a container)?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when I want to have access to my local docker from within a container I just mount the docker socket and the docker binary as volumes.

For example (I run this from docker for mac):

`docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker alpine sh`

From there you can run any docker command including scaling your services.
You can add those 2 volumes to your `docker-compose.yml`

EDIT1

In compose syntax this is what you can do

```
services:
  serviceX:
    image: yournamespace/yourimage:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
  serviceY:
     ...
```

ServiceX will have access to docker. Then it's up to the app you're running inside this service to call APIs.

Comment: works perfect on my mac for docker commands, any chance you have an idea how to use it on "docker-compose" commands?

Comment: Just edited the original answer to add the compose syntax

Comment: I am still not able to use docker compose command inside container X